# How to add express backend to existing react app

Tags: reactjs, express

My question is pretty much all in the title.

So I have built a react/redux frontend.
Now, the task is for it to be served with fresh Express installation.

Say, my api should be served from "/api/...", and react frontend should be at "/"

Is it just a matter of merging node-modules into one and configuring Express routes, or there is something else that needs to be done?

Comment: It should be ok "Is it just a matter of merging node-modules into one and configuring Express routes"

Answer (score 0):

A very good example of how to do this is available [here](https://github.com/mars/heroku-cra-node).

The main points of his configuration are these:

- You have two `package.json`s and two sets of dependencies.
- In development, you have two servers, and you configure your backend as a proxy in the front-end `package.json` file: e.g. `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"`
- In production, you compile your front-end code to static html, and route all non-api requests to the compiled html at the end of your express config:

The routing might look like this:

```
app.get('/api/foo', function (req, res) {
  res.send('{"foo":"foo"}');
});

app.get('/api/bar', function (req, res) {
  res.send('{"bar":"bar"}');
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../react-ui/build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Obviously all credit goes to mars for the super example app.